# Reference Error: variable is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got a variable called "nthchild" `var nthchild = ($(ui.selected).index() + 1);`
This gives me the nth-child of a list item with the class selected. I even log it in the console and it works fine. However when I try to use this variable but it doesn't work.

```
$("section:nth-child(" + nthchild + ")").style.marginTop = "200px";
```

So it should give the section a margin-top of 200px. But the console is giving me the error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: nthchild is not defined

You can find my code on this [codepen](http://codepen.io/tobiasglaus/pen/xgBeaJ)

```
$(function() {
    $("#selectable").selectable();
});

$(function() {
    $("#selectable").selectable({
        selected: function(event, ui) {
            var nthchild = ($(ui.selected).index() + 1);
            console.log(nthchild);
        }
    });
});

$("section:nth-child(" + nthchild + ")").style.marginTop = "200px";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because you define `nthchild` out of scope of the location you attempt to use it. To fix this place the `:nth-child` selector within the `selected` callback so that it's executed when the `selectable` is updated.

Also note that `.style.marginTop` is a property of a native Element which is not available on a jQuery object. Instead, use the `css()` method, or better yet, put the style in a rule in an external stylesheet and use `addClass()`. Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#selectable").selectable();

    $("#selectable").selectable({
        selected: function(event, ui) {
            var nthchild = ($(ui.selected).index() + 1);
            $("section:nth-child(" + nthchild + ")").css('marginTop', '200px');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't be $("section:nth-child(" + nthchild + ")").css({'margin-top':'200px'}); or document.getElementsByTagName("section")[nthchild ].style.marginTop = "200px";

Comment: Right. That works perfectly! But now the divs dont go back to their original position when I unselect them :/

Comment: @TobiasGlaus you can use jquery :not() selector add $("section:not(:nth-child(" + nthchild + "))").css('marginTop', '');